# Oauth isn't authorizing a read request

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

Ok here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace twitter_integration_v1
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oauth_token = "somekey";
        var oauth_token_secret = "somekey";
        var oauth_consumer_key = "somekey";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "somekey";

        var oauth_version = "1.0";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
        new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        var resource_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml";
        //var resource_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.xml";
        var status = "Another Status Update 3";

        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
            "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(status)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url),
                     "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                    "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
               "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
               "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
               "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );

        // Requesting now

        var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status);

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Now attempting to display homepage");

    }
 }
}
```

Ok now the thing is that above code is working fine for writing status updates through POST. However whenever i try to use a varaiation of it like

```
Console.WriteLine("Attempting to read");

        //var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status);

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        /*using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }*/

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

to receive status updates it the code just crashes at `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();` and sends in a 401 unauthorized. How come it is authorized for writing but not reading. Any help regarding where to start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to do something like this , where you have

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

do something like this

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)page.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I have solved the reading problem it seems i forgot to replace 'POST' with 'GET' in request.method property. Anyways really thanks for reading through such a long code.